# How to change app name when using localization

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, localizable.strings, cfbundledisplayname

I have wrote code in `InfoPlist.strings(English)` file like this:

```
CFBundleDiaplayName="Lo Demo";
```

But it doesn't work. My app name is `${PRODUCT_NAME}` in file named `xxx-info.plist`.

I have tried to delete the item `"Bundle display name"`, but the app name didn't change.

Comment: My app run in iOS 6.1 simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled it:

```
CFBundleDisplayName="Lo Demo";
          ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The right formate is

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Lo Demo";
```

You lost the "". It's work for me.